Issue writing unit tests for a jQuery datepicker plugin
the start of my plugin
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["jquery", "jquery-ui-dist"], factory);
  } else {
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function( $ ){
    $.extend($.ui, { multiDatesPicker: { version: "1.6.6" } });

...
    // Workaround for #4055
    // Add another global to avoid noConflict issues with inline event handlers
    window['DP_jQuery_' + dpuuid] = $;


I'm trying to  write unit tests for this plugin but I keep getting this error Exception during run: ReferenceError: jQuery is not definedin a NodeJS environment. Please note that I don't have an html file where use the puglin.
My test file
import 'jsdom-global/register.js';  // Automatically sets up and tears down JSDOM
import $ from 'jquery';  // Import jQuery
import { expect } from 'chai';  // Import chai for assertions
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js';  // Import jQuery UI datepicker
import '../jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js';  // Import the multiDatesPicker plugin (adjust path if necessary)

describe('multiDatesPicker Initialization', function() {

    before(function() {
        // Make jQuery globally available
        global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
        window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
    });

    it('should initialize the multi-date picker correctly', function() {
        const $input = $('<input>');  // Create a jQuery input element
        $('body').append($input);     // Append it to the DOM
        $input.multiDatesPicker();    // Initialize the multi-dates picker

        expect($input.hasClass('hasDatepicker')).to.be.true;  // Check if the datepicker is initialized
    });

 
});

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Where is define defined? The Error suggests that jQuery is not loaded or cannot be found.

It's an open source project, created by someone else,  that I'm trying to contribute to by writing unit tests. Where is that define keyword supposed to be or how can I get jQuery loaded in my test file? @Twisty

I am not sure, since its not shown here. I am guessing you are using some library and this is just checking if define() is loaded before proceeding and then is used to help define jQuery as a Variable. Since you did not post a [mcve], people may have to guess. Where did you find the original example?

Looks like your plugin factory expects jQuery to exist but in your test file you import jQuery as $, not as jQuery. Since the plugin factory (what you call "the start of my plugin") is "imported with side-effects" it is likely run before the code after the line "// Make jQuery globally available". Try to change in test file the line import $ from 'jquery' to import $ as jQuery from 'jquery' and remove both  = $ from the two lines that make jQuery globally available in your test file.
